# Flutter: Resize children in SliverGrid

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-sliver, sliver-grid

I am trying to build a BottomSheet where different emojis, images and gifs are displayed in a gridview. For this I am using a CustomScrollView Widget with SliverPadding and SliverGrid. My Problem is, that **I can not adjust the size of the images and gifs in the grid**. The emojis can easily be resized with the fontSize property.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
 CustomScrollView(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          primary: false,
                          slivers: <Widget>[
                            SliverPadding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                              sliver: SliverGrid.count(
                                crossAxisSpacing: 50.0,
                                crossAxisCount: 3,

                                children: <Widget>[
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: const Text('', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "like");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: const Text('', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "laugh");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: const Text('', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "surprised");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: const Text('', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "hot");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: const Text('', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "thumbsUp");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },

                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: const Text('', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "nice");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },

                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                              height: 20,
                                              width: 20,

                                    child:  Image.asset('assets/kiss.gif', height: 20, width: 20, fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "nice");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },

                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],

                       )
```

**And here is how it looks like at the moment (the kiss mouth is actually moving):**

[image]

As you can see the kiss is way too much, but I am not able to adjust its size. Whether with height and width or wrapping it in a SizedBox, nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by wrapping the children in Center Widgets:

```
 GestureDetector(
       child: Center(
         child:  Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                         child:  Image.asset('assets/kiss.gif')),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      postLike(widget.list[widget.index].reference, widget.currentUser, "kiss");
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },

                                  ),
```